# Can't read a file openFileInput Android

Tags: android

Trying to open a file
the file exists (and the check returns true)
 but in.available returns 0

if I look at the file with the device monitor I can see the file and it has a size...

```
if(fileExists(filePath) == false)
                return "ERROR";
            FileInputStream in = openFileInput(filePath);
            if(in.available() <= 0)
            {
                //THIS ALWAYS HAPPENS!!!
            }
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }
            inputStreamReader.close();
```

permissions set

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_LOGS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What does openFileInput do? 
It should be doing this:

```
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(filePath));
```

Comment: Apparently available() can legally return 0 even if there is data in the stream

Comment: Read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileInputStream.html#available()) for the definition of what available() means.